"command not found" while running runuser
I want to execute pm2 -s jlist as the user managing the service.
I can execute the command if I switch to user's shell, but I cannot do the same as root using runuser -l pm2_user -c 'pm2 -s jlist' because I get

pm2: command not found


type pm2 executed by user works with pm2:
pm2 is /home/pm2_user/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.2/bin/pm2

The command I used firstly was
runuser -l pm2_user -c 'pm2 -s jlist'

What is pm2? How was it installed? What is the output of which pm2 and does it work if you use that, the complete path, to run it?

You're running runuser with the -l option. From man runuser:

-, -l, --login    Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a real login:
[...]
•   initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME,
and PATH

So PATH may not be the same as when you're running pm2 -s jlist from the shell, and may be missing the path to which pm2 resolves:
% sudo runuser -l user -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
% sudo runuser user -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

Try and run runuser without the -l option:
runuser pm2_user -c 'pm2 -s jlist'

However if the PATH to the exectuable you're trying to run is added to PATH by, say, ~/.bashrc, or by something not sourced by Bash in non-interactive mode, I don't think there's a straightforward way to provide the environment in which pm2 will run with the same exact environment the user running pm2 would get in a normal shell, so, for the purpose of running a single command, the easiest way to do it I think would be to just run the executable referencing its full path:
runuser pm2_user -c '/home/pm2_user/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.2/bin/pm2'


I have the same issue pm2: command not found even if I try to run runuser with no -l option.

So the only way to correctly run command by root is only use its full path. But full path of command I can print if I logged in as service user, cause runuser whereis cannot print command path.

@palmasd1 Please add the output of type pm2 to your question, it's a PATH issue for sure, I guess it's installed in a PATH that is not sourced even when removing the -l option.

I've added the output.

@palmasd1 I think the fastest way in this case would be to just run runuser pm2_user -c '/home/pm2_user/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.2/bin/pm2' then. Not the cleanest, but it should work. If you want a better solution, please let me know where the path to this executable is set exactly (I guess in ~/.bashrc?)

It is fastest way if I know the resulted path. But this command would be used at hundreds of servers with different PM2 settings, and such servers are deployed by other admins I cannot affect to. So it's the reason why every time I need to know real path.

@palmasd1 What do you mean by different settings? It will always be an executable nested somewhere in ~/.nvm/versions/node, correct? If so, runuser pm2_user -c 'PATH="$PATH:/home/$USER/.nvm/versions/node" pm2', which will work regardless of the user running pm2 and Node's version. Otherwise explain where the exectuable may be, and runuser might not be the best way to do this.

At another server I have PM2 executable file at the "/usr/bin/pm2" path. I really don't know why it's located there cause I didn't deploy it. I have never worked with PM2, the only task I have for now is script infrastructure audit. This is the reason I cannot understand how to search PM2 while it is stored at the different locations.

@palmasd1 Probably because it hasn't been installed through npm, unlike in the instance you're working now. In fact, I think you should install pm2 globally at this point, and then use the path in the output of npm root -g. If you don't have the rights to do so, then you're out of luck, and your instances will have to rely on looking in non-standard paths, such as /home/pm2_user/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.2/bin/pm2 as well as standard paths.

@palmasd1If these two are the only possible paths, then runuser pm2_user -c 'PATH="$PATH:/home/$USER/.nvm/versions/node" pm2' will work. Otherwise, you'll have to add more paths, again, assuming you can't install the thing somewhere else more standard.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
